# Placement of Tasks from Dataflow Graph on a Physical Graph

Tags: graphs, optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, constraint-programming

I have a dataflow graph where a set of different types of tasks are placed in corresponding types of nodes.

Say the task types are called A, B, and C.

- A-type tasks are placed in all the leaf nodes of the dataflow graph.
- B-type tasks are placed in nodes with the data from any two nodes hosting A-type tasks, or one node hosting B-type tasks and one node hosting A-type tasks.
- If it is neither a leaf node nor a junction node receiving data from two separate nodes, then it is an empty data forwarding node (as shown in Figure 2).

These A-type and B-type tasks' hosting nodes make a tree-type structure, and the root node hosts the C-type task. The below figures 1 and 2 show two variations of such dataflow graphs/trees. Each task requires a storage and processing capacity.

I have another undirected graph network which is a connected graph but not a complete graph. Each node in the undirected graph has a specific storage and processing capacity. I want to use a mixed-integer linear programming formulation to place these tasks in the **same sequence** as in the dataflow graph/tree to this undirected graph network. Given the storage and processing capacities required for each task and of each node in the undirected graph, the objective is to select a subgraph of nodes from the undirected graph network which can host all the tasks in the same sequence in them and the nodes in the output subgraph are connected (i.e., there is a path between any pair of nodes).

Any hint or suggestion in this regard is highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what "map the dataflow graph to this undirected graph network" means.  What is the input to the algorithm, and what is the desired output?  What does "node connectivity is also enforced" mean?  Whether the problem is well known or not doesn't depend on whether you solve it with MILP or in some other way.  Can you [edit] your post to more clearly state the problem specification?

Comment: @D.W. I have edited the question. The input to the graph is a set of tasks and the undirected graph network. The output is a subgraph/tree where the source/leaf nodes host tasks of type A, the destination/root node hosts a C-type task, any intermediate node with a junction of two source/leaf nodes hosts a B-type task, and any other nodes that are only to ensure the subgraph/tree is connected are empty nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the edits.  I'm still struggling to understand the problem, and I'm overwhelmed by the amount of text - I find it hard to understand something with this much text all in one paragraph.  I might find it easier to understand if you broke it down into smaller pieces.  Maybe a series of definitions (e.g., a definition of task, dataflow graph, valid dataflow graph) followed by a specification of the algorithm (list of inputs, list of outputs, condition for the outputs to be correct / how they must be related to the input).

Comment: I still don't understand what your proposed approach to find a solution (based on MILP) has to do with whether this is a known problem.  My guess is, odds are that any problem this complex to describe is not going to be a standard "known problem".

Comment: My experience is that it's often more helpful to ask for how to solve a problem, then to ask if it is a known problem. In the former case, either someone gives you an algorithm, or tells you it has been studied in the literature and gives you a reference where you can learn more. Either way, you have learned something useful. In the latter case, you can only win if it has been studied in the literature and has a standard accepted name. Of course, if you already know how to solve it, then maybe there is nothing to ask and nothing more you need to know. So I'm not sure what the real need is.